# ping request not forwarded in one direction

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, gateway

Edit: I solved my issue just as I was finishing this insanely long post.  I had simply not enable ping reply in my windows firewall which is why I could not ping a computer on network 0 from network 1 or 2 (see below). And of course, when I tried to ping the internet router on network 0, it didn't work because I neglected to setup the non-default gateways on it like I did my windows.

So, I give you the 'right' way to setup a linux box as a simple gateway between subnets. Just remember to setup all your gateways on the clients correctly (simple rule: default gateway should be the route to the internet, then setup 1 gateway for every subnet attached to other gateways in your subnet.

I am creating a test network with an Ubuntu linux box connecting 3 subnets. Here is my topology:

```
               ***********************
               * Internet Router     *
               *    192.168.2.1      *
               ***********************
                         *                   ***************
                         *                   *  Client 0   *
                   ***************           *192.168.2.117*
                   * Switch      * * * * * * *  Windows    *
                   ***************           ***************
                         *                               
                         *  192.168.2.0/24 = Network 0
                         *
 Network 1         ***************        Network 2
192.168.1.0/24     *    eth0     *       10.25.0.0/16
       * * * * * * *             * * * * * * * 
      *            *eth1     eth2*           * 
      *            *             *           * 
      *            *             *           * 
*************      * Ubuntu Srvr *      *************
*192.168.1.5*      ***************      * 10.25.0.5 *
*           *                           *           *
* client 1  *                           * client 2  *
*           *                           *           *
*************                           *************
```

My ubuntu server's /etc/network/interfaces file is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.192
    network 192.168.2.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1

# Subnet 1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 10.25.0.1
    network 10.25.0.0
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    broadcast 10.25.255.255
```

I have uncommented `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl.conf

I also ran the command `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Client 1's default gateway is 192.168.1.1

Client 2's default gateway is 10.25.0.1

Client 0 on network 0 has 3 gateways:

1. Default: 192.168.2.1 (internet router)
2. 192.168.1.0/24: 192.168.2.192 (ubuntu eth0)
3. 10.25.0.0/16: 192.168.2.192 (ubuntu eth0)

I am testing this setup with ping.

1. I can ping any computer on any network from network 0.
2. I can ping any computer on network 1 or 2 form network 1 or 2.
3. The problem is I **cannot ping** any computer on network 0 from network 1 or 2

Using iptraf, I see the ping req coming from, say, 192.168.1.5 to 192.168.2.117 on eth1

I don't, however, see a response.

... Just figured it out (see edit at beginning).  If you made it this far, sorry to disappoint.

Comment: I figured it out, see my edit at beginning

Comment: When you manage to figure out the problem yourself, you can feel free to answer your own question by clicking the Answer button below. (New users need to wait 8 hours before marking the answer as accepted, though.) Welcome to Server Fault!

Comment: Yah, I tried that, but am twiddling my thumbs for the next 7 hours...

Comment: +1 for a well phrased question and drawing. You seldom see them nowadays.

Comment: I believe that restriction goes away at 10 reputation, so .. try it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue just as I was finishing this insanely long post. I had simply not enable ping reply in my windows firewall which is why I could not ping a computer on network 0 from network 1 or 2 (see below). And of course, when I tried to ping the internet router on network 0, it didn't work because I neglected to setup the non-default gateways on it like I did my windows.

So, I give you the 'right' way to setup a linux box as a simple gateway between subnets. Just remember to setup all your gateways on the clients correctly (simple rule: default gateway should be the route to the internet, then setup 1 gateway for every subnet attached to other gateways in your subnet.

Comment: I was just coming here to suggest that you needed to check you had icmp allowed on all the devices.